# could not locate named parameter [InboundResultsId] in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Im using nHibernate and trying to execute the following code:

```
string hql = "select a from Applicant a with (nolock) where a.Inbound_Results_Id = :InboundResultsId";


    try
    {
        IList<Applicant> applicants = _ws.Session.CreateQuery(hql)
                    .SetParameter("InboundResultsId", indata.Inbound_Results_Id)
                    .List<Applicant>();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        Logger.LogMsg("No applicant data was found when looking for unmatched applicants.");
    }
```

And I receive the following exception:

**could not locate named parameter [InboundResultsId]**

Any idea on why I am getting this error?

Thanks!
Flea

Comment: What happens if you change CreateQuery with CreateSQLQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. It turns out **Inbound_Results_Id** is not a property on my Applicant class.  My **Applicant** class has a property of a complex object called **InboundResult** which in turn it has a property called **Inbound_Results_Id**.  So all I needed to do do was this for my HQL:

```
   string hql = "select a from Applicant a where a.Inbound_Result.Inbound_Results_Id = :inboundResult and a.Harvest_Result_Processed = 0 and a.Applicant_Id not in (" + applicantIdList + ") and a.Status in ('Generated','Received')";
```

Here is the complete code:

```
string hql = "select a from Applicant a where a.Inbound_Result.Inbound_Results_Id = :inboundResult and a.Harvest_Result_Processed = 0 and a.Applicant_Id not in (" + applicantIdList + ") and a.Status in ('Generated','Received')";

IList<Applicant> unmatchedApplicants = new List<Applicant>();

try
{
    unmatchedApplicants = _ws.Session.CreateQuery(hql)
        .SetParameter("inboundResult", indata.Inbound_Results_Id.ToString())
        .List<Applicant>();
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    Logger.LogMsg("No applicant data was found when looking for unmatched applicants.");
}
```

Here is my Applicant class:

```
    public class Applicant : Person
    {

        public virtual long? Applicant_Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Account App_Account { get; set; }
        public virtual string Carrier_Name { get; set; }

        public virtual InboundResult Inbound_Result { get; set; }

        //Applicant Demographics
        public virtual string Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my InboundResult class:

```
public class InboundResult
{

    public virtual long? Inbound_Results_Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string File_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual string Header_Line { get; set; }
    public virtual string Contents { get; set; }
    public virtual string Support_Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Create_DateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Update_DateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual string User_Name { get; set; }
}
```